# Writing a function that works with a .txt file in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, file

Hi I'm trying to write a function that has a path to a .txt file as input and outputs a list of all the words in the file in Python 3. I apologise in advance for my lack of understanding and poor formatting.

I managed to open the file but cannot really work with it as I'd hoped. I tried just making a long string of the entire file and then use  `str.split(" ")` to get a list with all the words in the file. However, I just get `<_io.TextIOWrapper` which I'm not even sure what it means even after searching it up. Additionally, I tried to use `str.strip()` to get rid of the `\n` but then I got the Errormessage: `"<_io.TextIOWrapper" object has no attribute "split"` .

This is basically how I've tried opening the file so far and it did work. However, as previously mentioned I can't really make much more with it.

```
def do_sth(inp):
       with open(inp,"r") as file:
```

Is there an easy way to just open .txt files and for example count the words or sentences etc? (I have done this before but only with a few senteces or words that were not in a file)

edit: more context: This is what I have come up so far. If i do it any other way it will just take each character of the words. The text file I'm working with is a long text and hence I need to somehow first get rid of the punctuation, and then split the text at each space so I have a list of words. Not really sure how to work with this.

```
def task(inp):
    with open(inp,"r") as file:
        contents = file.read()
        words = contents.strip().split(" ")
        while "\n" in words:
            words.remove("\n")
        print(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f=open("file.txt", "r")
contents =f.read()
l = list(contents)
```

Now you got a list and can output that in your console

with `print(l)`
source: [reading and writing files in python](https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did get the list correctly now thanks! However, the \n is still in there. What can I use to get rid of it?

Comment: Hi, you could do this with something like:
`l_clean = []

cleaning = [l_clean.append(i) for i in l if i != "\n"]`

Comment: That does not seem to work now it just gets each character but not the words

Comment: Sorry, can you provide more code? Or how does your list look and how should it look?

Comment: Yes I have edited the question with more context and my code so far.

Comment: Actually I think I've got it now. I'll just make a new post with all the information otherwise this one does not make any sense. Thanks for your help